# Simple way of extracting a value from a file using regex (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

Hi I’m currently learning Regex in python, made a simple exercise for myself, where I have a file full of lines of data, and I only want to extract a value from each line that has ‘outer’ in it.

**file.txt**

```
ABC 134234ed6  outer +
deE  325353ed5 out +
ABC 133234ed0 outer +
deE  325353ed5 out +
ABC 135234ed0 outer +
deE 125353ed5  out +
ABC 455234ed0  outer +
deE 125353ed5  out +
```

Here, I only need to get the number after `ed` (6,0,0,0) in each line that has `outer` in it. **My code is currently working, but I was wondering if there are simplified ways to do this**, only using regex.

Here is my code:

**main.py**

```py
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

regex = re.compile(r'\d +(outer) \+$')
results = []

for line in lines:
    match = regex.search(line)
    if match:
        result = match.group()
        results.append(int(result.split(' ')[0])) # this

print(results)
```

It prints `[6, 0, 0, 0]` which is what I want. But the logic involves splitting the string and then getting the first item (the line marked `# this`), which I believe can be put into the regex directly and the value can be extracted using `group()` directly.

I know there are similar questions like this already exist, but I think my question is specific enough that you just have to help me make the logic simpler, thanks!

Comment: anubhava's answer tells you what you need to do, although maybe doesn't explain exactly why. The point is that you are using grouping parentheses unnecessarily for a group that you are not interested in extracting (the `outer `) and not using them for a bit that you are actually interested in extracting (the `\d`). Once this is fixed, you can then use `match.group(1)` to extract the bit matched by the first (and in this case, only) set of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @alaniwi !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic point is that you should use the grouping parentheses for the part of the regexp that you are interested in extracting.  The minimal fix is to put the `()` around the `\d` rather than the `outer`, so that you can then use `match.group(1)` -- see anubhava's answer.  Beyond this, as you are in fact already reading the whole file into memory, so clearly it is not necessary to reduce memory by reading a line at a time, you could in fact read it in as a string and then use `re.finditer`.  This will help simplify the code.  Example:

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

regex = re.compile(r'(\d) +outer \+\n')

results = [int(match.group(1)) for match in regex.finditer(text)]

print(results)
```

This gives:

```
[6, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note that in the regex there is now `\n` (newline) to replace the `$` in your original regex -- the `outer \+` must by followed by a newline.

---

**Addendum**

To answer the question of what to do if the file is really really large: just as you cannot use `f.readlines()` if it would exceed available memory, you also cannot use `f.read()`.  Your best approach is probably then the following (similar to anubhava's answer but avoiding use of `readlines`).  Note that the basic issue with the use of capture groups in the regex still remains the same.

```
import re

results = []
matcher = re.compile(r'(\d) +outer \+$').search
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = matcher(line)
        if match:
            results.append(int(match.group(1)))

print(results)
```

Comment: If the file would be really really big, would finditer perform better than reading them one line at a time?

Comment: @Hedy I am assuming based on the fact that you are already reading the whole file into memory (using `readlines`) that the file is *not* really really big. If it is, then there will be a memory problem, and it will be exactly the same memory problem with the code I've suggested here. In that case instead, you would probably want something similar to anubhava's solution except that instead of using `readlines` you loop over lines by doing `for line in f:` (inside the `with open...`) so that it doesn't store all the lines in memory simultaneously.

Comment: @Hedy I've added an addendum to my answer showing what I think you would do then, more easily than I can do in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor your code and remove all redundant regex splitting, matching:

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

reg = re.compile(r'(\d+) +outer \+$')
results = []

for line in lines:
   m = reg.search(line)
   if m:
       results.append( int(m.group(1)) )

print (results)
```

**Output:**

```
[6, 0, 0, 0]
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/za6iSF)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\d+)` +`: Match 1+ digits and capture this in group #1 followed by 1+ spaces. Note that you are only interested in getting this value` (\d+)` hence using this in capture group.
- `outer \+`: Match `outer` followed by a space and `+` character
- `$`: Match end

Comment: Conversion to int may still be needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1: `"outer"`, if present, must follow `"edX"`**

In this case you can match the string with the regular expression

```
r'(?<=ed)\d+(?=.*\bouter\b)'
```

If there is a match it will be the digit(s) following `"ed"`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/528uro/1/) | [Python code](http://tpcg.io/vRtg0tZ9)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=ed)         : positive lookbehind asserts that current position
                  is immediately preceded by 'ed'
\d+             : match 1+ digits
(?=.*\bouter\b) : positive lookahead asserts that current match is
                  followed by 0+ characters other than line terminators,
                  followed by 'outer' with word boundaries
```

**Case 2: `"outer"`, if present, may precede or follow `"edX"`**

In this case you can match he string with the regular expression

```
r'^(?=.*\bouter\b).*ed(\d+)'
```

If there is a match the digit(s) following `"ed"` will be contained in capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/528uro/2/) | [Python code](http://tpcg.io/CItHQ4re)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^               : assert beginning of string
(?=.*\bouter\b) : positive lookahead asserts that the string
                  contains 'outer' with word boundaries
.*ed            : match 0+ characters other than line terminators,
                  followed by 'ed'
(\d+)           : match 1+ digits in capture group 1
```

The word boundaries (`\b`) are present to avoid matching words such as `"router"` and `"accouterment"`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining regex in details, I didn’t know about `\b` and the look ahead and look behind stuff!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

results_str = re.findall(r'.*ed(\d+).*\bouter\b.*\+', ''.join(lines))

results = [int(x) for x in results_str]

print(results)
```

Output:

```
[6, 0, 0, 0]
```

**re.findall** could be used to find all matches in the string

> Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.
> If one or more capturing groups are present in the pattern, return
> a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
> has more than one group.